# How to display next and previous record through jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating an online application which can save data and display the data from the database. So I want to show only one record from the database e.g when user click on the NEXT button it should display the next record nut only one record when the user click on PREVIOUS button it should display the previous record. I am using NetBeans IDE and create the application using JSP. How can i do this using JSP ?.

Thanks for the positive response.

Comment: search for java database pagination

Answer (score 0):

It should be a combination of Database row filtering by its size and sending appropriate requests using JSP like having a query.`select * from TABLE where CONDITION limit FIRST RANGE;`

Then in JSP, the intial request would have FIRST=0, RAnGE=20 (say)
for Next, U can specify next=CURRENT+1 and prev=CURRENT-1.

Pagination can be handled in variety of ways, pick the way which suit youe needs.